# Multiple apps in one icon for the iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, folders

My husband's iPhone has the multi app icon and wanted to get the same on my new iPad.

Is it possible to get it on the iPad?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "multi app icon"? Are you referring to [iOS Folders](http://www.apple.com/ios/)?

Answer (score 7):

I think you are talking about iOS folder. If so, touch and hold one icon till icons begin dithering. Then drag and drop one icon on an other icon which of two you want to folder together. Your ipad will suggest you a folder name. You may change or assume that. Then push the home button.

Comment: Also, the iPad must be updated to iOS 4.2 to have this functionality